# Syscall rename error in npm when installing angular-cli un ubuntu terminal in android userland

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm, angular-cli

When i try to install angular-cli on my ubuntu terminal, it shows an rename error. **I'm using Ubuntu terminal on Android using userland application**.

my node version is v12.22.12
my npm version is 8.13.2

when i enter the command `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` it shows the following error.

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/17547761
npm ERR! dest /root/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/56/8a/7901b7c9a78b8b398bfadcea1ea13d4c33e24771d3c82e9f59f8628a7ef3cddebcdab8ab59657890d8aa698f9419b45d87cd98136802e09d0ed6850a4279
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/json-schema-traverse: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/17547761' -> '/root/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/56/8a/7901b7c9a78b8b398bfadcea1ea13d4c33e24771d3c82e9f59f8628a7ef3cddebcdab8ab59657890d8aa698f9419b45d87cd98136802e09d0ed6850a4279'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-06-30T11_58_10_175Z-debug-0.log
```

The contents of the log file is,

````
917 error syscall rename
918 error path /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/17547761
919 error dest /root/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/56/8a/7901b7c9a78b8b398bfadcea1ea13d4c33e24771d3c82e9f59f8628a7ef3cddebcdab8ab59657890d8aa698f9419b45d87cd98136802e09d0ed6850a4279
920 error errno ENOENT
921 error enoent Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/json-schema-traverse: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/17547761' -> '/root/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/56/8a/7901b7c9a78b8b398bfadcea1ea13d4c33e24771d3c82e9f59f8628a7ef3cddebcdab8ab59657890d8aa698f9419b45d87cd98136802e09d0ed6850a4279'
922 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
922 error enoent
923 verbose exit 1
924 timing npm Completed in 40418ms
925 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1656590293986
926 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1656590294236
927 verbose code 1
928 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
928 error     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-06-30T11_58_10_175Z-debug-0.log```
````